# Is Flatstrap 3 available in compiled form?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

I have some problems with compiling Flatstrap 3. I don't know how to get compiled version of it using GRUNT? If anybody have compiled version of Flatstrap 3, I will be most grateful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. install nodejs and npm: may vary from platform to platform, but you will find info [here](http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm)
2. install grunt-cli: `npm install -g grunt-cli`
3. [download flatstrap](https://github.com/littlesparkvt/Flatstrap-for-Bootstrap-3/archive/master.zip)
4. unzip into some_local_directory
5. `cd some_local_directory`
6. then execute `npm install`
7. then finally `grunt`

The result in some_local_directory/dist contains the "compiled" Flatstrap 3.

All these steps are documented more or less in [Flatstrap documentation](https://github.com/littlesparkvt/Flatstrap-for-Bootstrap-3/#compiling-css-and-javascript).

Comment: Yes, I understand all of this steps, but on my windows i have errors conected with grunt: Please intall Jekyll... It abort process of building css. I search that error and finally i can't solve that. Have you compiled package of Flatstrap 3. I havent another idea :( Sorry for my bad english, also.

Comment: Then install jekyll following these steps https://github.com/littlesparkvt/Flatstrap-for-Bootstrap-3/#running-documentation-locally but I don't think you need it (save generating documentation). Bad english is ok in my book - mine is not exceptional either - just try to make your question more specific explaining exactly what your problem is, along with error output and relevant data/config files.

Comment: So, you think that Jekyll isn't essential to build it? I process with your instruction and i have all the time the same problem. Can you recommend me other "flat" bootstrap themes (with sharp corners like Flatstrap)?

Comment: My full error when i build: Running "jekyll:docs" (jekyll) task / Warning: Please install Jekyll before running this task Use --force to  continue. / Aborted due to warnings

Comment: Your full error tells you the documentation generation task was aborted, which is irrelevant to css generation (and which is fixable by installing jekyll) - and you should really update your question, not add additional comments - or ask a different question. 2 cents.

Comment: Listen here. I also didn't have Jekyll, and also got the error, AND it didn't compile the css and js files in the dist directory strangely enough. I had to use the 'grunt dist' command, and then it finally worked (without installing Jekyll).